# The Gherkin (an egg shaped building) - equation for the curve in order to calculate the surface area of revolution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, interpolation

I am trying to calculate the surface area of revolution for ***The Gherkin***, an egg-shaped building in London, UK. Not sure about how to obtain the equation of the curve but I have the data points that allowed me to graph it in Excel but the equation, as it turns out, isn't simply quadratic.

Pls does anyone know any graphing programs that can determine unusual curve equations from a list of data points??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have enough data points, it might make sense to model the building as a stack of truncated cones exactly determined by the known points rather than try to (possibly imperfectly) fit a curve to those points.

Answer (score -1):

polyfit in Matlab is great. Returns a polynomial of degree n

Something like:

X = [ x co-ordinates in order (with spaces in between) ];

Y = [ y co-ordinates in order (with spaces in between) ];

p = polyfit(X,Y,n)

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Why is a polynomial adapted a good thing? Aren't there different points with the same X / or the same Y? The user David K proposed a model of truncated cones instead,